# django: how do I migrate this view to class-based generic view equivalent?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have trouble transforming the following code into the new django 1.3 class-based generic view format. Specifically, I don't understand how I can pass the 'extra_context' to the class based view. Can someone help me transform this code to the new notation? or post a link to a good example? I've read the docs but the example is very flimsy.

```
def return_event_list_object(request, username, queryset, entries_per_page, param1, param2):
    ...
    ...
    return object_list(request, queryset = queryset,
            template_name = 'myapp/list_events.html', 
            paginate_by = int(entries_per_page), 
            template_object_name = 'event',
            extra_context = {'param1': param1, 
                            'param2': param2, } )
```

I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`extra_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/generic-views-migration/#extra-context) section of the docs explains how to add items to the context:

> Class-based views don't provide an extra_context argument. Instead, you subclass the view, overriding get_context_data(). For example:

In your case, try:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'param1': kwargs['param2'],
            'param2': kwargs['param1']
        })
    return context
```

Comment: and how do I have to call the MyListView then to pass the parameters? I only see calls like MyListView.as_view(). Is this where I pass the parameters?

Comment: Yes, I believe you pass the parameters to `MyListView.as_view()`.